# how to access different sda from terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, partitioning

When I run `lsblk` in my terminal, I get [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtlB6.png) items under sda section. As we can see, the mount point for `sda2` is "". I want to access this from terminal, but I don't know how can I do that. I know how to access these parts from GUI, where we can click on "Other Locations" in the file manager, where all sda are listed. However, I currenty can not do that, because I am currently not at actual location of my desktop, and I want to access these locations remotely from terminal using ssh. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add an empty directory somewhere like /mnt/sda2 with "sudo mkdir /mnt/sda2", then mount sda2 there "sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2" and then "cd /mnt/sda2

Answer (score 4):

Create a folder to house your filesystem like so :

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda2_access
```

Proceed to mount the filesystem with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/sda2_access
```

Now, you can cd into `/media/sda2_access` to get to your files.